# How I can add new module to odoo 15

Tags: odoo

I am new to Odoo and I need to know what is the basic steps of adding a new module.
More specifically I need to know how to add custom modules to the addons-path.

In Odoo document they explain this step as this

```
$ ./odoo-bin --addons-path=../custom,../enterprise/,addons
```

but did not work for me.

Comment: Check the [prepare the addon directory](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/03_newapp.html#prepare-the-addon-directory) section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding a new module you should do these steps:

1. Build your module with your written code or scaffold command.
2. Add the module path in your config file at addons-path = '',''
3. Change your URL like this: http://localhost:8091/web?debug=1
4. Go to apps and from up tabs
5. Select update app list and refresh your page.
6. Now you can see your module in the apps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not getting your custom module in Odoo after adding the path then you can try to add the full path of your folder into addons-path.

To get the full path of your custom folder just right-click on the folder and go to properties and find the path of your folder.

Also, you have to make sure to Apply the **Update App list** in your Odoo App Dashboard after restarting the server with custom addons.